# How can I save an arrayList permanently without database

Tags: android

How can I save an arrayList permanently without database.

If you could include an example it would be great.

Thank you!

Comment: What's in the `ArrayList`?  Strings?  A custom class?

Comment: why u want to store without database

Comment: As @Dave said, it depends what objects are in your ArrayList?

Comment: do u want to make it accessible though the application

Comment: @sunil 1:to learn different way,and second i already have a database i would like to keep the with one that i can just read and not to insert

Comment: @Blundell it is a custom ArrayList (ArrayList<History>HistoryList),   in history i have String and long.

Comment: @Sunil Yes i would like to insert the data from an activity(c) and to read and show the data in activity(d) in the same app with all the history.

Answer (score 6):

If it's just the one ArrayList and you don't have any complex ordering to your datastore, I would just save it out internal storage in binary format. That will save you a lot of overhead trying to encode and decode the file in a text format such as XML or JSON.

A link to check out is [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Edit: I put together a quick and dirty [github repo](https://github.com/blcooley/ArrayListTest) to give an example. It's not something I would just copy and paste into a project, but it should show you the basic mechanics.

Edit 2: Note that all the Objects inside the ArrayList need to implement Serializable or be primitive types for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

Export the ArrayList to a file maybe in a specific format ( Xml,JSON,csv etc. ) Then ready upon the data when you need it.

Pseudo:

```
String data;

i = 0;
Loop Array
   data += array[i]

   i++;
End loop

Write data to file
```

You can make it as easy/hard as you want ofc. But you get the idea i think :)

Comment: Ok,Thanks! do you have an example for me?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables)?

But you will lose data after a switchoff or restart.

Comment: so its not good for me i need this data even when i switch off

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Serialize stuff from Java. The objects inside the `ArrayList` should implement the Serializble Object. Than, you can save the resulting binary file to storage and reload it. here's an example of how to do it: http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_Serialization_Example_%28Java%29