# How to serialize ArrayList

Tags: android

How can I serialize an ArrayList and Save it in a file?

Comment: What are the contents of the ArrayList? Is it a known class that you can serialize or are you looking for a general solution?

Comment: the content its class that i wrote mostly String,and yes i am looking for serialize.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I save an arrayList permanently without database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498039/how-can-i-save-an-arraylist-permanently-without-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is to serialize the class, the objects of which populate the ArrayList. If this is a simple class, composed mainly of primitive types and doesn't have a deep structure, this will be easy. You can choose JSON, protocol buffers or even XML for the representation. If you succeed on this, it will be straightforward to serialize the ArrayList.